# How to identify IATA or ICAO codes from string

Tags: c#, regex, replace, split

I am developing a flight related API and I need to split the carrier code and the flight number of a code that I am receiving. For example:

```
UA775 -> UA and 775
```

this case is trivial. But there are different sorts of IATA and ICAO codes and the patterns I identified are:

```
letter letter letter     {digit}+
letter digit             {digit}+
digit letter             {digit}+
```

So three letters and then a bunch of digits, a letter and a digit and then a bunch of digits or a digit, then a letter and then a bunch of digits. In the last two cases it should work like this:

```
X3567 -> X3 and 567
5U9997 -> 5U and 9997
```

Is there a way I can do this in c# with the help of Regex matching? Currently this is my code, that is missing the last two cases:

```
// e.g:
carrierAndFlightNumber = "X3567";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)");
Match result = regex.Match(carrierAndFlightNumber);
string carrier = result.Groups[1].Value;
string flightNumber = result.Groups[2].Value;
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
@"^([A-Za-z]{3}|[A-Za-z][0-9]|[0-9][A-Za-z])([0-9]+)$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IMdE4P/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `([A-Za-z]{3}|[A-Za-z][0-9]|[0-9][A-Za-z])` - Group 1:

  - `[A-Za-z]{3}`  - 3 letters
  - `|` - or
  - `[A-Za-z][0-9]` - a letter and a digit
  - `|` - or
  - `[0-9][A-Za-z]` - a digit and a letter
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 2: 1+ digits
- `$`  - end of string.

Comment: That is perfect. I forgot to mention that there are also 2 letter codes but with this expression it was easy to fix. Thank you so much

Comment: `^([A-Za-z]{2}|[A-Za-z]{3}|[A-Za-z][0-9]|[0-9][A-Za-z])([0-9]+)$` this should be the right regex... thanks for this though

Comment: I just realized there's a Virgin flight `VIR137Y` :( so this should should work `^([A-Za-z]{2}|[A-Za-z]{3}|[A-Za-z][0-9]|[0-9][A-Za-z])([0-9]+[A-Za-z]?)$`

Answer (score 0):

Without using regex you can use a simple routine that identify your three cases:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace IdentifyIATA
{
    public static class Iata
    {
        public static Tuple<string,string> CodeIdentifier(string code)
        {
            var first = code.Substring(0, 3);
            if (first.All(char.IsLetter)){
                return new Tuple<string, string>(first, code.Substring(3));
            }
            return new Tuple<string, string>(code.Substring(0, 2), code.Substring(3));
        }
    }
}
```

The first element of the tuple return the first part of your code and the second the second: I used this small program to test it:

```
using System;

namespace IdentifyIATA
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = Iata.CodeIdentifier(args[0]);
            Console.WriteLine($"Code: {result.Item1}, {result.Item2} ");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```